# How to edit a table in order to count the number of points in the same location?

Tags: qgis, postgresql, excel

Using QGIS, I have a point shapefile that has multiple points with same coordinates across different locations.

I need a count of those points.

For example there are 15 features that have the exact same coordinates in location A, and there are 12 features that have the exact same coordinates in location B. A very useful result would be maybe to have a new shapefile with location A 15 and location B 12

I have a column with postcodes (though there are postcodes with different spatially distributed points) and columns with coordinates if it helps.

Comment: You already asked the same question : http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/194919/how-to-print-maps-portions-one-by-one-in-qgis-2-14-2 . See my answer on the other post.

Comment: I asked for labeling first but then I figured out that I needed to go further and actually count them. Will try your answer now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would like to get distinct geometries, use in postgis:

```
SELECT DISTINCT your_geom_column FROM your_table;
```

If you are interested in the number of points at the same positions:

```
SELECT your_geom_column, count(*) FROM your_table GROUP BY 1;
```

Comment: Gonna port my data over to postgis (will take some hours) and then test your answer